# Increase ignore_above property in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using elastic search with nest 5.0

I need to increase ignore_above from default 256 to 512.

Can I do this by the Attribute mappings?

Otherwise how can I do this using the fluent API?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with attribute mapping. Check [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/17eb95bee01f9fd63759fd2a0a0df54d765ec43e/src/Tests/Mapping/Types/Core/Keyword/KeywordAttributeTests.cs) test.

Comment: Keyword arrtibute makes the string field(text type) to keyword type, then the code below returns zero results.

`GET myindex/_search
{
    
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": {
                "query":    "somesearchtext"
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @GSH please add more detail to your question. An example may help :)

Comment: Well the point is, if I add the [Keyword(IgnoreAbove = 512, Index = true)] attribute on the property then my "match" does not work on that property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[Keyword(IgnoreAbove=512)]` to change the value:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "mytype")]
class mytype
{
    // default: will be mapped to both keyword (keyword search) 
    // and text (full-text search)
    public string defaultString { get; set; }

    // by default ignore above is set to 256 
    [Keyword]
    public string keywordType { get; set; }

    // change ignore above
    [Keyword(IgnoreAbove=512)]
    public string longKeyword { get; set; }

    // text type, full-text search
    [Text]
    public string textType { get; set; }

    // store but not searched
    [Text(Index = false)]
    public string textTypeNotSearchable { get; set; }
}
```

This is the created index in ElasticSearch for the above type:

```
"defaultString": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "keywordType": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "longKeyword": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 512
  },
  "textType": {
    "type": "text"
  },
  "textTypeNotSearchable": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": false
  }
```